# Running a project from GitHub

Tags: ios, xcode, github

When downloading an iOS project from `GitHub` there are times where some left over from previous settings makes it difficult to compile.

I am having such a case now. I get two errors.

1. error: No account for team "FT4NWG456Y". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.
2. error: No profiles for 'com.app.me.LocationNotifier' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.app.me.LocationNotifier'.

This FT4NWG456Y identification is coming from outside.
If I search it in Xcode, it finds it but does show me where it is.

For the profiles I use automatic setting as much as I can.

Is there a simple way of getting rid of those 2 errors.

Comment: Change the Team under your target's Signing & Capabilities settings.

Comment: You can also select a *Simulator* to just compile it. Otherwise you should deal with automatic/manuel  signing.